# OnPropertyChanged causes massive amount of Action allocations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF application which displays images in a grid. The user has the possibility to scroll fast through images by moving the mouse while left clicking. So this means there are a lot of images changing at a fast rate.

I noticed a performance degradation for 24 and 40 element sized grids (which are the largest). I identified the cause of the slowdown was a lot of garbage being created which caused lots of blocking gen0 and gen1 garbage collections. By reducing the amount of allocations I could improve the peformance from about 10 fps to 25fps.

Still not completely satisfied with this, I analyzed a bit more and noticed there is a massive amount of Action objects being produced, exceeding all other types being allocated by far. When scrolling, I get around 50000 allocations of Actions per second.

I tracked this further down with a memory profiler, and the cause is one PropertyChanged event which fires every time an image shall change. This internally causes some events to be registered and deregistered, this event manager used the class ReaderWriterLockWrapper. Indeed, every time the properties WriteLock or ReadLock are accessed, an Action will be allocated, as seen in the reference source:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Internal/ReaderWriterLockWrapper.cs,7553fcec2d50ae8a,references

`CallWithNonPumpingWait(()=>{_rwLock.EnterWriteLock();});`

I noticed the code is this way since framework version 4.7. Is this intended? This alone causes 16MB worth of Action instances in my application when I continuously scroll for 8 seconds. Also, the way I see it, this lambda could just be an instance member.

Comment: You've thoroughly analyzed the problem, but what is your actual question to the StackOverflow community? You're not asking us whether the code in the reference source was intentionally written by the authors of the .NET Framework?

Comment: My question would be if there is any way to avoid this, maybe by hooking in some other behaviour for this certain event, but I assume there is not. I guess you are right, I should probably ask this in the Microsoft forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is solved in .NET 4.8 by enabling EnableWeakEventMemoryImprovements